# Grunt does not load config.json to build Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs

I copied the config.json to the bootstrap source folder and followed the compiling instructions on Bootstrap's site.

It build bootstrap with everything where I only wanted what was in the config.json file.

What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The Grunt build doesn't use the `config.json` file. Only the web-based Customizer uses it.
To customize with Grunt, just edit the`.less` files and/or `Gruntfile.js` directly.